# Is it possible to find subset number from an adjacency matrix?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Not sure if there is a method for this, but is there a way to obtain the amount of intersected combinations or subsets of combined vertices, from the adjacency matrix?
For example for a complete graph $K_4$ with one branch taken out, say $AC$

$$A---B$$
$$|\quad\quad / \quad\quad|$$
$$D---C$$

Defining adjacency matrix with vertices defined as $A_1=A,A_2=B,A_3=C,A_4=D$

$$
a_{ij}=
\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & A_i \cap A_j \neq \varnothing  \\
0 & A_i \cap A_j = \varnothing \\
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

Would have the adjacency matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

Is it possible to deduce the cardinality of subsets obtained from this adjacency matrix below, or does it have to be done through some other way? Or is there a formula to calculate something like this?

$\{ \{ A,B,C,D\}, \{AB,AD,BC,BD,CD\} ,\{ABD, BCD\},\{ABCD\}\}$ which is 4,5,2,1 total of 12

Comment: So you want the number of nonempty subsets of the vertex set of the starting graph which are such that for any two nodes in the particular subset those two nodes are linked by an edge in the starting graph. Is that right? [I realize the way I put it is long-winded...]

Comment: Yes, but if possible can it also be done for nodes linked by 2 or more edges? So that the other combinations like $ABD, BCD, ABCD$ can be found as well? This would extend the definition to $A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k$, etc.. I'm not sure if this goes  into tensors or if it can be done with just the adjacency matrix, that's why i'm asking

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the rule that excludes $ACD$ but does not exclude $ABCD$. Certainly there are "$2$ or more edges" between nodes $A,C,D$.

Comment: If one is allowed to include any subset such that there is a *path* in the starting graph beetween any two vertices in the subset, then you are looking for "connected" subsets of the starting graph. But your example list does not do that, as in your starting graph any nonempty subset of vertices is "connected".

Comment: $ACD$ does not have a path back from $C$ to $A$, i.e. $A \cap C =\varnothing$, so by extension $A \cap C \cap D = \varnothing \cap D = \varnothing$

Comment: @MishaLavrov Just to make it more clear, since there exists $A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k \cap A_l \neq \varnothing$ for some $i,j,k,l$, in particular for $(A \cap B) \cap (B \cap C) \cap (C \cap D) \neq \varnothing$, you are noting the case for $(A \cap C) \cap (C \cap D) \cap (A_i \cap A_j) =\varnothing$

Comment: What does $A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k \cap A_l$ mean? I was assuming you were using $A_i \cap A_j \ne \varnothing$ as weird shorthand for "there is an edge between $A_i$ and $A_j$", but you actually seem to be treating these as intersections of sets, and I don't know what the sets are.